# How to populate jsGrid columns and rows dynamically in ASP.Net WebForm using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I am trying to use the jsgrid as the data grid control in my asp.net WebForm page. The source data will be a JSON response of a web service call perform through AJAX call. I was doing some online searching but couldn't  find any clear example of how to use this plugin with dynamic columns/rows.

Did anyone use this plugin with dynamic columns/rows?

Comment: Is your web service publicly avaiable? If so, I can create a JS Fiddle to demonstrate how it works. I just need the url of your web service.

Comment: Sorry, it is an internal project. Can you just use a dummy webservice?